# Permission denied when executing php from command line, and crontab

Tags: php, cron, centos

I am attempting to create a cronjob under the user apache, but I get permission denied errors for files that are accessed by the program. The specific file that my php script cannot access is /var/www/html/amazon/amazon_data.txt. Here is me checking the permissions, and testing to see if I can write to the file:

```
bash-3.2$ whoami
apache
bash-3.2$ ls -l /var/www/html/amazon/amazon_data.txt
-rwxrwxr-- 1 apache apache 1082 Apr  3 15:43 /var/www/html/amazon/amazon_data.txt
bash-3.2$ vi /var/www/html/amazon/amazon_data.txt
```

Now I try to run a script that tries to access the file I get this warning:

```
bash-3.2$ /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/amazon/amazon_inventory_sync.php
PHP Warning:  Module 'json' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  fopen(amazon_data.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/amazon/amazon_inventory_sync.php on line 26

Warning: fopen(amazon_data.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/amazon/amazon_inventory_sync.php on line 26
Unable to open amazon_data.txt!bash-3.2$
```

Why can I access and edit the file with the user just fine, but not in the php script when executing it via command line? There is no issue when I run the script from a browser.

Edit: I can run it fine under the user soh, who is in the group apache. apache is also in the group apache.

Comment: Who is the script assigned to?

Comment: The script is assigned to apache

Comment: and what is happening on line 26 of the file?

Comment: `$file = fopen($filename, "a+") or die("Unable to open $filename!\n");`

Comment: hmmm.   I'm not sure.  Can you post your script?

Comment: I don't think so, it spans several files. Also, I get three different results when I run this script. First, if I access it in my web browser, it runs. fine. But if I let the cron job run, it partially runs but errors out when attempting to do Curl. Last, if I try to run it manually in the command line, I get the error I mentioned. I thought fixing this error might fix all the other errors.

Comment: ok, I really don't know.  I was just thinking that something might be happening outside of the normal permissions, or some sort of chain reaction occurring because of the earlier warnings

Comment: OK, thanks though! The cron job works, it's just not working from command line, which is acceptable I guess. I was able to fix the problem I had, that only appeared when doing the cron job, by running it every minute and having a log output.

Comment: for command line, maybe you have run it as sudo?  anyway, glad  it's working

Answer (score 3):

The issue was due to the file being requested not being a literal location. This is the code which did not work:

```
$filename = "amazon_data.txt";
$file = fopen($filename, "a+") or die("Unable to open $filename!\n");
```

This may work fine when the script is run remotely via HTTP, but it may cause issues when running cron jobs or execution in the terminal. Changing the `$filename` to be the full location fixed this issue.

```
$filename = dirname(__FILE__)."/"."amazon_data.txt";
$file = fopen($filename, "a+") or die("Unable to open $filename!\n");
```

Why does this happen? I am guessing instead of the php file's folder being used, it was using a directory which the apache user did not have access to, such as the current working directory that the command in terminal was being executed from.